# Hold and swipe can't work together

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, platformer

I Have a character in my game that must go when player hold finger at the screen, but when I swipe character first go, and then do swipe. (for example jumping - character first go, and only then jump).
This my code for touch:

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startTime = Time.time;
            startPos = touch.position;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            endTime = Time.time;
            endPos = touch.position;
            swipeDist = (endPos - startPos).magnitude;
            swipeTime = endTime - startTime;

            if (swipeTime < maxTime && swipeDist > minSwipeDist)
            {
                swipe();
            }
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && isTap == 0)
        {
           hold();
        }
    }
```

This my code for a hold:

```
  void hold()
{

        moveVelocity = 3f;


}
```

And for swipe:

```
void swipe()
{
    Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;
        if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) > Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
    { 
           if (distance.x > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Right swipe");
        }
        if (distance.x < 0)
        {
           Debug.Log("Left swipe");  
        }
    }
    if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) < Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
    {
        if (distance.y > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Up swipe");
        }
        if (distance.y < 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Down swipe");
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is**: When player swipe left character first go, and only then do swipe left. I want player swipe, without going forward. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need to wait just a bit, and collect some position data where you call Hold, to make sure the player didn't intend to swipe.

Something like this:

```
endPos=touch.position;
swipeDist=(endPos-startPos).magnitude;
holdTime=endTime-startTime;
if(holdTime>minHoldTime&&swipeDist<holdThreshold)hold();
```